# How to redirect the user from the login screen to the home page in react-native

Tags: node.js, react-native, express

I am building  mobile app using expo and node js (express)
I build the home screen and profile screen and i am move between them using navigation (Drawer)
and I build log in && sign up screen.

My question now, how to control user flow
if he pass correct information in log in screen to redirect him to the home page, and if he pass un-correct information not allow him to see the home page

this is my App.js

```
import React from "react";
import MyDrawer from "./components/slidbar";
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <MyDrawer />
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

and this is my log in page

```
// import EnterName from './App/Components/EnterName
import React from "react";
import {
  AppRegistry,
  View,
  Text,
  StyleSheet,
  TouchableOpacity,
  KeyboardAvoidingView,
} from "react-native";

import { requireNativeViewManager } from "expo-core";

import LoginInputs from "./LoginInputs";

export default class LoginPage extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.onPressLearnMore = this.onPressLearnMore.bind(this);
  }
  onPressLearnMore() {}

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <KeyboardAvoidingView behavior="position" disabled>
          <View
            style={{ marginTop: 50, marginLeft: "auto", marginRight: "auto" }}
          >
            <Text
              style={{
                fontSize: 20,
                fontWeight: "bold",
                color: "#CC7575",
                marginTop: 150,
              }}
            >
              Welcome To Nany App !
            </Text>
          </View>

          <LoginInputs />

          <TouchableOpacity style={{ center: "auto" }}>
            <Text style={style.textButton}>Login</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>

          <View style={style.center}>
            <TouchableOpacity>
              <Text
                style={{
                  textAlign: "center",
                  padding: 20,
                  margin: 10,
                  color: "#CC7575",
                }}
                onPress={this.props.onPressCreateAcc}
              >
                create an Account ?
              </Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
        </KeyboardAvoidingView>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
const style = StyleSheet.create({
  title: {
    color: "#8E9BEA",
    textAlign: "center",
    marginTop: 50,
    fontSize: 30,
    fontWeight: "bold",
  },
  center: {
    marginLeft: "auto",
    marginRight: "auto",
    marginTop: 30,
  },
  textButton: {
    width: 140,
    padding: 10,
    fontSize: 20,
    marginTop: 100,
    marginLeft: 100,
    fontWeight: "bold",
    borderRadius: 30,
    color: "white",
    textAlign: "center",
    backgroundColor: "#CC7575",
  },
});
```

Can someone help?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to make two separate navigations. One for login/signup and one for connected users. Like that the user cannot return to the login without logout and vice versa.

So in your app.js you would have something like

```
if(connected){
    // Connected nav
    return (
        <NavigationContainer>
          <HomeNavigation />
        </NavigationContainer>
    );
}
else{
    // Login/Signup
    return (
        <NavigationContainer>
          <LoginNavigation />
        </NavigationContainer>
    );
}
```

OR

```
return (
     <NavigationContainer>
          {connected ? <HomeNavigation /> : <LoginNavigation />}
     </NavigationContainer>
 );
```

Comment: how can i determine  if the user connected or not ( in which part of the code) is it front end(in which component) ? or backend?

Comment: Authentication is always in backend, the best is to return a token attached to your user that you store on your device for later auto login and requests